# cmake, boost::filesystem linking error (undefined directory_iterator.operator!=)

Tags: c++, boost, linker, cmake

I'm using CMake (2.8.3), Boost::filesystem(1.42.0) in Ubuntu 10.10. The code compiles OK but I keep getting the following error when linking:

```
CMakeFiles/sample.dir/sample.cpp.o: In function `main':
sample.cpp:(.text+0x1af8d): undefined reference to `int operator!=<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >(boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > const&, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code in question is the following:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main()
{
  string folder;
  string extension;
  fs::directory_iterator end;

  folder    = ".";
  extension = ".zip";

  for (fs::directory_iterator i(folder); i != end; ++i)
  { if (fs::is_regular_file(i->status()))
    {
      if (boost::algorithm::ends_with(i->leaf(), extension))
      {
        cout << i->leaf() << " has extension .zip" << endl;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, I have:

```
find_package(Boost 1.4.0 COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(executable
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

but I've also tried with:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.4.0 COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(executable
    ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY})
```

and many other combinations of the above.

The linker is complaining about the `!=` operator for the `directory_iterator` type. If I look to the contents of the header in `/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.cpp` I can see that the operator is defined there. Any ideas why this is happening?

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the missing include files:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

and namespaces (std), and defining a macro for this "fs" shortcut of your code:

```
#define fs boost::filesystem
```

Then I tried the first CMakeLists.txt approach that you mentioned, and it worked... I also have the same system as you.

What I would recommend is using `MESSAGE` in CMake to inspect these $Boost_* variables and debug a bit the compilation system with it...

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruben. I wish I could delete my stupid question. I started from scratch as you did and it's working OK.

Comment: Do _not_ use #define for namespaces: namespace fs = boost::filesystem

Comment: Thanks @Maik, I actually never define aliases for namespaces, I just wanted this code to compile touching it as little as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, except it was my compiler (VS 2010) complaining that there was no operator!= that takes a left-hand operand of type 'boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator'. It turned out that I had declared my end iterator like this:

```
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator endDir();
```

When I removed the parentheses, everything compiled and linked just fine. I guess the compiler was interpreting the original line as a function named `endDir` that returned a `directory_iterator`, which still doesn't quite explain why it was complaining about the left-hand operand, and not the right-hand operand.

This issue has been described by Scott Meyers as [C++'s "most vexing parse."](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=767929)